# no compil webView_flutter

Tags: webview-flutter

I have a problem with the WebView_flutter package, when I establish the dependencies, and I import the packages, flutter pub get compiles without problems, but when I use a webView element in my code, this gives an error message as if it was not declared.

I tried putting the computer into developer mode but nothing works